# What became of the daughter of Cixi‘s photographer?

Tags: china, qing-dynasty

„Princess“ [DerLing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Der_Ling) has written several books on Empress Dowager [Cixi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empress_Dowager_Cixi). Her brother [Xunling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Yu_Shuinling) took the only photographs of Cixi known to me. But on some of the pictures from 1903 (example below) a little girl is seen, who has been identified (f.e. by Grant [Hayter-Menzies](https://grantmenzies.wixsite.com/author)) as Lili/Lilly, the daughter of Xunling.

What is known about the subsequent life of this girl?

[image]

Comment: @justCal That article seems to be about the wedding of [Yu Xingling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Yu_Hsingling), who is the brother of [Yu Xunling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Yu_Shuinling) (the photographer) and would therefore be the uncle of that little girl.

Comment: @Jan Thanks, that explains the date issue. (*and I apparently need new glasses...*)

Comment: @justCal The names are really quite similar.

Comment: @Jan inChinese Tradition there was a tendency for a generation to share a name character. Therefore we have DeLing, Rongling, Xunling and perhaps Xingling

Comment: Good question... Perhaps you could share it on the Chinese language stack? We sadly do not have many China experts here

Comment: @NeMo I fear it would be off topic there…

Comment: I meant link to the question in the chat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [this photo](https://ids.si.edu/ids/deliveryService?id=FS-FSA_A.13_SC-GR-249), the little girl at left is Lily Yu, daughter of Xunling Yu, court photographer and brother of Der Ling. This has been confirmed by family of Mme Dan Rongling, sister of Der Ling and Xunling.

One more thing I can add about Lily: she was born in 1893. As to what happened to her later, I could never find this out. The family seem to have disappeared in the melée of Japanese invasion, Mao's victory and the cultural revolution. Her father, Xunling, died in 1944. I write about the subsequent life of Der Ling's sister, Mme Dan, who lived into her nineties in Beijing. She was attacked and killed by Red Guards in the street outside her apartment near the Forbidden City during the cultural revolution.

My 2008 biography of Der Ling contains everything verifiable I could find out about the family.

Comment: There is a growing literature in China rehabilitating the role of Yuan Shikai, "a Chinese military and government official who rose to power during the late Qing dynasty and eventually ended the Qing dynasty rule of China in 1912." This may seem tangential to the question but there may be something related to the people in this photo in that body of work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuan_Shikai  I wouldn't rule it out.